# How to get "registration_ids" from Firebase FCM?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

From [FCM documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group) here tells me how to send message to a device group, so I've to send something as followed:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

However, I don't found there is any clear explanation told me how to get `"registration_ids"` from Firebase FCM.
I could only get "registration token" using `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()`.
So anyone can tell me how to get `"registration_ids"` please?

Comment: **registration_ids** MEANS FCM tokens.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`"registration_ids"` is an array of the registration tokens acquired by calling `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` on a device. If you put multiple registration tokens in the array, the same push notification will be sent to each.

If you only want to send a notification to one device with a `registration_id` of `4`, your `"registration_ids"` array need only contain one value like so: `"registration_ids": ["4"]`

If you want to send a notification to multiple devices, call `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` on each device to get the token then populate the array with values like you already have.

Comment: im sorry, im still don't get it. how do i know token A from device A is id "4" and not "5" or "6"? how does it know when i simply put "4", "8", "12", the registered devices are token F , G, H , those numbers aren't just simply put it right? how can i get those numbers?

Comment: owh u mean those numbers are just example? we actually have to replace them with the actual token?

Comment: right, those numbers are just placeholders in their example. You replace those numbers with the registration tokens for the devices you want to send it to

Comment: Very confusing that they did not use something that actually looks like a device token for the placeholder. Then they also call it something different to boot.

Answer (score 2):

The sample request you included:

```
https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/notification
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=API_KEY
project_id:SENDER_ID

{
   "operation": "create",
   "notification_key_name": "appUser-Chris",
   "registration_ids": ["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

is for *creating* a Device Group.

The `registration_ids` parameter refers to the [Registration Tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#credentials) you want to add in that specific Device Group. Described as:

> An ID generated by the FCM SDK for each client app instance. Required for single device and device group messaging. Note that registration tokens must be kept secret.

Meaning that it is generated on the client app side and acts as the identifier of that specific device (*client app instance*).

To send downstream messages to a device group, simply make use of the [`to`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) parameter:

> This parameter specifies the recipient of a message.
>
> The value can be a device's registration token, **a device group's notification key**, or a single topic (prefixed with /topics/). To send to multiple topics, use the condition parameter.

passing the `notification_key` as value.

Answer (score 0):

If for someone this question is relevant, then:
I've tried to register `notification_Key`, which I need for further usage with `notification_key_name = uid` and `registration_ids = [fcmToken]` in `func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String)` and succeeded in that